# Getting a java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> while trying to compile java files

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file

I am a beginner in Java. I started a tentative OOP project for which I am creating a bunch of different packages. Since my project is git tracked, I am trying to recompile everything before syncing. To simplify the process of compiling through my VS Code Powershell, I created a small windows batch script
called *packageUpdater.bat* that deletes all previously compiled java packages and then should recompile all indexed java sources:

```
cd "C:\path\to\project\folder"
del ".\Confrontation\*" ".\Defines\*" ".\WorldBasics\*"
javac -d . ".\sources\Defines\*.java" ".\sources\WorldBasics\*.java" ".\sources\Confrontation\*.java"
pause
```

I tried running *packageUpdater.bat* from the Powershell terminal but then ran into this error:

> C:\path\to\project\folder>javac -d . ".\sources\Confrontation*.java"

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 18: .\sources\Defines*.java
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option$37.process(Option.java:693)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.handleOption(Option.java:1088)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs(Arguments.java:381)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init(Arguments.java:193)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:229)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)

The deletion part executes properly and I get to validate each delete ops. And I know the paths to the files are correct because when I run that same **javac** command in the Powershell directly, it runs without any issue. I am new to using batch files as well so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: I _very_ strongly recommend that you adopt one of Maven or Gradle, the two standard tools for doing this; they make life dramatically easier. That said, the problem is in your [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: You should first decide which script interpreter you really want to use for Java compilation. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` interpreting a batch file has lots of limitations. Its successor PowerShell `powershell.exe` is much more powerful and is therefore better for such tasks. But syntax of [cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/) is completely different to syntax of [PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/). A question with tag `powershell` __and__ tag `cmd` is often a clear indication that the questioner knows nothing about both interpreters and so has to first study them.

Comment: It is of course also possible that you write a small Java application to do the rebuilds of Java projects. Then you would not need to learn the syntax of `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`. That would be most likely the better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi for the explanations. I could use a java application but I wanted to get more familiar with the use of terminal. I wasn't really aware of the differences between the windows cmd and the Powershell. I went and read more about Powershell and replaced the batch file by a Powershell script file instead and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I received on the question it appears that the issue comes from the cmd not preprocessing my command to provide all the files that match the wildcard name, as I expected it would. Thus java crashed because it does not support wildcard references.

A couple solutions were suggested but I went with replacing the batch script *packageUpdater.bat* by the Powershell script *packageUpdater.ps1*. I also altered the script to remove the change directory operation because now I can run it directly from the project directory in vs code powershell terminal. I also replaced the UNIX command aliases from my previous script by the correct Powershell commands:

```
Remove-Item ".\Confrontation\*",".\Defines\*",".\WorldBasics\*"
javac -d . ".\sources\Defines\*.java", ".\sources\WorldBasics\*.java", ".\sources\Confrontation\*.java"
```